# Write and read from subprocess in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pipe

I need to send informations to a bot launched by a client. I've tried to do something like

```
bot_process = subprocess.Popen(argv, \
                   stdin=subprocess.PIPE, \
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    bot_stdout = bot_process.communicate(message.encode())[0]
    print(bot_stdout)
```

But function communicate() stop the process after one call.

I need to send continually informations to my bot and listen his response. Do you have any solutions to `run bot before loop and write in bot stdin + listen to bot stdout inside the loop` ?

Comment: You'll need to read from `bot_process.stdout` and write to `bot_process.stdin`, not use the "one-shot" `.communicate()` function.

Comment: Thank you ! ```print (bot_process.stdout.readline())``` seems to freeze my client. How can you read stdout ?

Comment: If you need to be able to do other things while waiting for outputs, you'll either need a separate thread, or `selectors`.

Comment: No, i need to wait for outputs, but ```print (bot_process.stdout.readline())```never read anything i suppose, because everything is freezed. My bot is a while True: input + print

Comment: If the other process waits for input before printing anything, then naturally you'll need to send it something first.

Comment: Yep like this
```
while True:
    bot_process.sdint.write(b'test')
    print(bot_process.stdout.readline())
```
this doesn't work for me

with a bot like :
```
While True:
    test = input()
    print(test)
```

Comment: You're not writing a newline – `input()` reads until one. As far as your bot is concerned, you're just leaving it hanging. Try `.write(b'test\n')`. :)

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not working, is it ok on your side ?

Comment: You will also need to make sure the stdin stream is not buffered, or call `.flush()`, e.g. `bot_process.stdin.flush()`.

Comment: YES IT WORKS; THANKS